# Populate additional/extra fields only in list from another collection (with lambdas)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an original collection, `List<Reviewers>`, and a new one `List<ReviewPerson>` where some fields from `Reviewers` will be copied to `ReviewPerson`.

The new list is constructed in a special way and not directly from `reviewers.stream().map(...)`. But at the end, I need to copy 2 additional columns that exist in each bean, `status` and `comments`.

```
List<Reviewers> originalList = ... // from DAO
if (!originalList.isEmpty()) {
   List<ReviewPerson> newList = new ArrayList<ReviewPerson>();

   // this fills out some columns of the ReviewPerson, not all;
   // must use this partial construction from service class
   newList.addAll(service.initialPopulation()); 

   // At the end, need to copy: (1) status, (2) comments
   // ...
}
```

The problem is I can't do this,

```
originalList.stream()
    .map(obj -> new ReviewPerson(obj.getField1(), obj.getField2(), 
                                 // ...
                                 obj.getStatus(), obj.getComments()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

because I'm not constructing new objects in the collection. What should I do?

Comment: *"What should I do?"* First try to figure out how you would do it without streams. Second, you need to define how you match up a `Reviewers` with a `ReviewPerson`, and then create a `Map` keyed by the match-up field(s), so you can iterate one collection and lookup the other.

Comment: If you cannot insert that copying into `service.initialPopulation()`, you will have to iterate `newList` afterwards, find the `Reviewers` for each `ReviewPerson`, and copy the data. Using streams vs. for loop vs. forEach won't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common solution is to stream the (presumably corresponding) **indexes** of the lists and use the same index to access both lists:

```
IntStream.range(0, originalList.size()).forEach(i -> {
    newList.get(i).setFieldA(originalList.get(i).getFieldA();
    newList.get(i).setFieldB(originalList.get(i).getFieldB();
    // etc...
});
```

But to be honest, this may be streaming for the sake of streaming. Sometimes a good old-fashioned straight-forward `for` loop is just a better solution.

Comment: Haha, was just about to add that second sentence ;D `for(int i = 0; ...)` is perfectly fine here.

Comment: It's not about being appropriate but about readability and efficiency here. The IntStream does not improve over an indexed for loop in this example, while possibly adding a performance overhead. Use streams when you can actually benefit from the stream methods (map, filter, limit...) to break down your processing into steps. But don't fall into the golden hammer trap and try to solve every minor problem by starting with `list.stream()...`

Comment: @geneb. it's a matter of taste, mostly, but I usually go with streams if I can create a single assignment (`result = data.stream().mapsAndFilters().collect()`) or if it's a oneliner `.forEach` call. If I need to open a block I'd usually just use a loop.

Comment: Plus, in your case here, using a stream to really improve the code is not possible as you need to process two lists in parallel. As Mureinik said, the IntStream just replaces a normal for loop for the sake of "using streams".

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind an extra dependency, and if `Reviewer`s and `ReviewPerson`s are indeed corresponding, I'd suggest using the [jOOλ](https://github.com/jooq/jool) library and its [`Seq.zip()`](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.14/org/jooq/lambda/Seq.html#zip-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Iterable-) method (`Seq` is a subtype of `Stream`) together with a [`Tuple.consumer`](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.14/org/jooq/lambda/tuple/Tuple.html#consumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) overload.

With the above, you can end up with such a concise piece of code:

```
Seq.zip(newList, originalList).forEach(Tuple.consumer((reviewPerson, reviewer) -> {
    reviewPerson.setStatus(reviewer.getStatus());
    reviewPerson.setComments(reviewer.getComments());
}));
```